# RailsアプリをHerokuにあげたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

```
heroku create
git push heroku master
```

ここまで成功したのですが、

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

を行うと、

```
ETIMEDOUT: connect ETIMEDOUT 50.19.103.36:5000
```

このようなエラーがでてデプロイに成功できません
どのようなエラーかわかる人おられますか??

Comment: localでdb:migrateは正常終了しますか？

Comment: はい、db:migrateは正常終了しています。

Comment: もっとlogを載せると回答が付くかもしれませんよ？

Answer (score 2):

logを見ないとはっきりとはわかりませんが、おそらく5000番ポートが利用できなために発生しているのではないでしょうか？herokuからの応答を受け取らないようにdetached指定して試してみてはいかがでしょうか？

```
$ heroku run:detached rake db:migrate
```

なお、上記を実施する前に、別のコンソールで

```
$ heroku logs --tail
```

としてログを監視しておけば、何が起こっているかわかるかと思います。
実施後、に

```
$ heroku logs
```

でもいいかもしれませんがリアルタイムでログを見た方が直感的にわかります。